# problem using freestylesvg

Tags: compositing-nodes, svg

My goal is to render the following blender template as svg via blender's built-in svg-exporter plugin:

[image]
(zip file can be obtained [here](https://wiki.blender.org/uploads/b/b4/M-130Blueprint.zip))

The final svg file however doesn't look like the result shown above:
[image]

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, Freestyle SVG Export is meant exclusively as a stroke export solution, for the freestyle part of the render only

It is not a full featured rendered solution, for backgrounds and diffuse colors, nor would it even be possible to reliably export the whole rendered output as an SVG file.

I am pretty sure if you tweak the settings of the SVG file in an external editor like [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) or any other vector graphics editor capable of opening or importing an SVG file, you can easily achieve the look you are aiming for.

[image: Freestyle SVG in Inkscape]

For an alternative solution check out the excellent [SVG Output Script](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?282824-SVG-output-script)

Comment: thank you Duarte Farrajota Ramons. This answer was very helpful!