# Export 3d model as SVG

Tags: export, svg

I have made a complex 3d model in blender and I was wondering if it is possible to export it as SVG.

Thanks!

Comment: Also see my answer here for alternative methods http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70604/problem-using-freestylesvg/70614